# Using 'chunks' together with 'with' on Laravel query builder

Tags: database, performance, laravel, laravel-5

dunno if this is possible at all.. I'm trying to query a large set of data with relations like so:

```
    Parent::with([
        'child' => function($query) {
            $query->('published', '=', true);
            $query->with('child.of.child', 'some.other.child');
            $query->chunk(400, function($childs) {
                // how is it now possible to add the $childs to the parent result?? 
            });
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: Well, after some trying and diggin in the query builder code I have found a solution:

Answer (score 0):

```
$parent = [];
Parent::with(
    [
        'childs' => function ($query) use (&$parent) {
            $query->where('STATUS', '!=', 'DELETED');
            $query->with('some.child', 'some.other.child');
            $parent['models'] = $query->getParent()
                                          ->getModels();
            $query->chunk(
                400, function ($result) use ($query, &parent) {

                $query->match($parent['models'], $result, 'child-relations-name');
            });
        }
    ])
         ->get();
```

Now $parent['models'] contains the tree with all the nested child relations... Dunno if this is the smartest way to do so, but it works for now.